# Run Angular and ASP.NET Web API on the same port

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, cors

I am currently using angular to issue API call to an API server running ASP.NET. However, I have a cross-origin issue as for angular development, I am using localhost. While in the production version they will all run under the same domain using IIS.

Is there a way to run the angular app on the same port with ASP.NET?

P.S.: I am also open for other alternatives on solving this issue.

Comment: They can’t run on the same port but you can configure a proxy to route your requests to your api

Comment: i think you could sub domain the api .. api.example.com

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem, then I've found [this post on medium](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-ways-to-connect-to-the-server-using-angular-cli-b0c6b699716c), hope this works for you.

Edit:
Actually the solution that I've used is from that article.

The idea is that you can't "publish" the API and the Angular app on the same port, but you can use a proxy to connect from the Angular app to the API on the other port.

**Update**: sorry for not answering this long time ago.

To deal with the cors issue (in this case) you can use a proxy with the `ng serve` command.

For example, in my case I have used a `proxy.conf.json` file like this:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

This code rewrite the url on every request to `/api/*` to the `http://localhost:3000` where your api is listening.

So, to illustrate, if in angular you make a request like `http://localhost:4200/api/users` it will be redirected/rewrited to `http://localhost:3000/api/users` solving the cors issue.

Now, the way you have to run your angular application is different.

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Comment: "The idea is that you can't "publish" the API and the Angular app on the same port" I should say this is not true and very misleading. Certainly you can bundle the asp.net core web api and angular app in one project and publish it to the same port. The only trick you need is to add a routing rule in Startup.cs like below:                  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "api",
                    template: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                        );

Comment: @SilentSojourner That's possible if the .net core api and the angular app were "created" (VIsual Studio allows this option) together and the api is just serving the app as static files on the `/` route. In that way the api routes everything from `/api/...` to the controllers and everything from `/...` to angular and his own routing. In every other way, you should use some proxy on the angular side to handle the problems like CORS.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to achieve that with IIS successfully! I know the post is old but hopefully, it will save time for solution seekers :)

First (just a reminder) ensure that you have .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed on IIS machine (link could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)). Bear in mind that it will require at least WinSrvr2012R2 to run.
Now copy published .net core API solution folder to the server. The same for Angular - next reminder here: execute *ng build --prod* then copy *dist* folder to the server.
Then configure IIS - create a new web site that points to the Angular app folder. Your Angular app should run at this point (but obviously there is no API yet).

Go to application pools - you will see the pool created for your application. Open basic settings and change CLR version to 'No managed code'.

And finally, click on your Web Site and 'Add application' under it. Point to dotnet core API folder and name it using some short alias. Now you should have a website structure with the application included.

If your angular app URL is:

```
https://myiissrvr/
```

your API is under:

```
https://myiissrvr/[ALIAS]/
```

DONE

Final remarks:

Usually, web API using URL structure like

```
https://myiissrvr/api/[controller]/[action]
```

So after bundling it together, it will look like:

```
https://myiissrvr/[ALIAS]/api/[controller]/[action]
```

With that approach, you should be able to attach multiple web API services under statically served Angular website - each one under its own alias. Potentially it might be useful in many scenarios.

Comment: Angular routes override the API routes and when i try to make an API call i get error 404 as the request is managed by Angular, do you know how could i solve it?

Comment: I guess it is regarding to web.config file you are using for Angular app. Please try to google it or raise a new question with web.config details.

Comment: that worked perfect. thank you

Comment: @RobertOstrowicki , I know that post is old but maybe You can tell me, so basically You got WebApplication with angular artifacts and angular webconfig , and folder inside with REST , but inside the rest there is also web.config for .Net, so could You tell how You resolve it ?:)