# .NET Core and Angular 8 WebSocket handshake error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket

I've been playing around with Angular 8.x for a week now. Today I actually tried to do a .NET Core App with Angular 8.x. I'm on .NET Core 2.2.x with Angular 8.x. When I run the app through Visual Studio 2019, I see the app takes a long time to actually load in the webpage which is different than running solely Angular. I checked the Chrome Browser Console and I see the following:

`sockjs.js:1683 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:41211/sockjs-node/909/dtwlrua0/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

I don't have a strong networking background but I assume this is the problem. How do I fix it?

As a side note, this is a basic (at least to me) application so not a lot of processing going on. I'm actually using [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-an-angular-8-app-with-asp-net-core/) tutorial. It took ~35 seconds according to the diagnostics section in Visual Studio to actually get data to display on the page (just a list of posts from C# Corner RSS Feeds).

EDIT: I forgot to mention (but anyone who uses a .net core/angular combo probably will catch it). I had to modify the default ClientApp that got generated with the .NET Core application. It was on Angular version 6. I deleted the folder and used the angular cli to create the ClientApp piece so that I could use Angular 8.x.

Comment: Are you intending to use a web socket? If so, can you share both client and server websocket code?

Comment: @theMayer I'm not exactly sure what a websocket is in regards to this tech stack and why it is useful. It sounds like if I am though, the client and server code are tightly coupled?

Comment: @theMayer See update, I actually scaffolded the ClientApp independently of Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I met the same problem in Edge browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a little conceptual knowledge here would be useful.  Visual Studio has this pre-packaged Angular thing which (in my opinion) is configured in a rather clumsy and hokey way so as to almost certainly not work correctly.

Angular applications are single-page apps. You build them according to the process documented at the [Angular Site](https://angular.io/start), using the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to assist you in this process. When you build your app in dev mode, it's going to try to connect to the webpack server to be notified of updates (thus, when you use `ng serve`, it will automatically recompile and refresh the page). This feature is not present in a production build (`ng build --prod`).

**Serving an Angular App**

Fundamentally speaking, the ASP.Net project is useless as far as the actual Angular application itself goes. When you compile the Angular code, the `ng build` command runs webpack, among other processes, producing a handful of `.css`, `.js`, and a single `index.html` page which renders your app (the name of the page can be configured).  Any web server capable of serving static files can serve `index.html` and thus run your app.

However, most Angular apps need some sort of a backend. This is where the .NET core app can come in handy. You would call back to your .NET core backend from your Angular front-end using [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http).

I have my Angular app working with .Net core in both production and test configurations. For production, I have the following:

- A regular site configured in IIS with the ability to serve static files (for the Angular application)
- A virtual directory at `/api` which hosts the packaged/published version of the ASP.Net core API project. Note that this project has no hard link to the Angular application
- We have shared object definition code between the two projects - I built a code generator which produces Typescript for the Angular app and C# for the back-end based on [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema).

For doing testing/development, I have set up a proxy configuration for the webpack server. Thus, clicking the "Run" button in VisualStudio starts the API project listening on `localhost:5800`, and the `ng serve` command starts the Angular webpack server on `localhost:4200`.  Requests to `localhost:4200/api` are proxied to `localhost:5800`.

Comment: How do you setup the proxy for the webpack server?

Comment: Use proxy.conf.json

Comment: No such file in my project. Obviously missing something?

Comment: Yeah you have to add one. Google for a detailed step by step.

Comment: For anyone else looking here, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753407/run-angular-and-asp-net-web-api-on-the-same-port to add the Angular proxy.